# Python, Flask, Gunicorn Error: Unrecognized Arguments

Tags: python, heroku, flask, gunicorn, procfile

I am running my app `app.py` using Python and Flask. I'm trying to deploy it to Heroku, and I followed the steps in [this tutorial](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/getting-started-with-python-o), including making a Procfile and requirements.txt. However, whenever I run `heroku local`, I get the following error:

```
web.1  | [2015-09-26 17:36:32 -0400] [19422] [INFO] Starting gunicorn 19.3.0
web.1  | [2015-09-26 17:36:32 -0400] [19422] [INFO] Listening at: http://0.0.0.0:5000 (19422)
web.1  | [2015-09-26 17:36:32 -0400] [19422] [INFO] Using worker: sync
web.1  | [2015-09-26 17:36:32 -0400] [19425] [INFO] Booting worker with pid: 19425
web.1  | usage: gunicorn [-h] [--auth_host_name AUTH_HOST_NAME]
web.1  | gunicorn: error: unrecognized arguments: app:app
web.1  | [2015-09-26 17:36:32 -0400] [19425] [INFO] Worker exiting (pid: 19425)
```

I've deployed apps successfully on Heroku before, but never have gotten this error. My Procfile is simply one line: `web: gunicorn app:app`.

Can anybody tell me how to fix this?

**UPDATE**: 
Modified some of my code and now when I run `heroku local`, it runs fine:

```
web.1  | [2015-09-28 18:52:13 -0400] [70650] [INFO] Starting gunicorn 19.3.0
web.1  | [2015-09-28 18:52:13 -0400] [70650] [INFO] Listening at: http://0.0.0.0:5000 (70650)
web.1  | [2015-09-28 18:52:13 -0400] [70650] [INFO] Using worker: sync
web.1  | [2015-09-28 18:52:13 -0400] [70653] [INFO] Booting worker with pid: 70653
```

However, when I deploy my Heroku app, I get an Application Error, and when I check the logs, I see the same error as before:

```
2015-09-28T22:50:54.775077+00:00 app[web.1]: 2015-09-28 22:50:54 [3] [INFO] Starting gunicorn 18.0
2015-09-28T22:50:54.776176+00:00 app[web.1]: 2015-09-28 22:50:54 [3] [INFO] Using worker: sync
2015-09-28T22:50:54.776052+00:00 app[web.1]: 2015-09-28 22:50:54 [3] [INFO] Listening at: http://0.0.0.0:24995 (3)
2015-09-28T22:50:54.786067+00:00 app[web.1]: 2015-09-28 22:50:54 [9] [INFO] Booting worker with pid: 9
2015-09-28T22:50:56.004336+00:00 heroku[web.1]: State changed from starting to up
2015-09-28T22:51:42.659042+00:00 heroku[router]: at=error code=H13 desc="Connection closed without response" method=GET path="/" host=bobawithjames.herokuapp.com request_id=1afab4c0-484e-456b-be05-3086ee0711cd fwd="160.39.250.29" dyno=web.1 connect=1ms service=39ms status=503 bytes=0
2015-09-28T22:51:42.604331+00:00 app[web.1]:                 [--noauth_local_webserver]
2015-09-28T22:51:42.604323+00:00 app[web.1]: usage: gunicorn [-h] [--auth_host_name AUTH_HOST_NAME]
2015-09-28T22:51:42.604335+00:00 app[web.1]:                 [--auth_host_port [AUTH_HOST_PORT [AUTH_HOST_PORT ...]]]
2015-09-28T22:51:42.633611+00:00 app[web.1]: gunicorn: error: unrecognized arguments: hello:app
```

Anyone know what's going on now?

Comment: try to rename your file to `main.py` and change Procfile to: `web: gunicorn main:app`

Comment: @ahmed I tried that and got the same error. Any other suggestions?

Comment: I'm having the same issue - anyone have a fix?

Comment: In your procfile, where do you specify the log flag?

Comment: @GamesBrainiac I didn't specify the log flag - should it make a difference? I tried adding the flag and I still get the error.

Comment: Is it possible that I'm missing certain dependencies? Right now my requirements.txt has the following:

Flask==0.10.1
Jinja2==2.7.1
Werkzeug==0.9.4
gunicorn==18.0

Comment: I had this same problem, it ended up that I had ArgumentParser attempting to get arguments from CLI - I commented that out and it works.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I managed to solve my problem, with the suggestion that @euxneks proposed, as well as some messing around with Google OAuth 2.0.

Essentially, the tutorial that I had been using, [Python Quickstart for Google Calendar API](https://developers.google.com/google-apps/calendar/quickstart/python), was using `argparse` to get flags for credentials. However, it was also calling `tools.run`, which is deprecated. So instead, I decided to follow a [different, more up-to-date tutorial](https://developers.google.com/api-client-library/python/auth/web-app), which walks you through using OAuth 2.0 with a Python Web App.

Answer (score 21):

I was able to solve this problem by replacing **args = parser.parse_args()** in my app with **args, unknown = parser.parse_known_args()**

Comment: Actually this solved my problem with Flask on GAE thanks hero.

Answer (score 5):

The issue was with having argparse in my script that is being ran by flask/gunicorn. Put these inside a:

```
if __name__ == "__main__":
    import argparse
    ...
```

This way if it's ran directly you can still parse the arguments running it standalone.

Answer (score 1):

I was running into the same issue when following the [tutorial](http://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/getting-started-with-python#define-a-procfile).  I removed the `--log-file` flag shown in their example.
In addition, I also modified the string so it references the wsgi.py application under my app directory [/app/wsgi.py] as follows:

```
web: gunicorn app.wsgi
```

Hope this helps!