# gunicorn: error: unrecognized arguments: -b

Tags: linux, flask, gunicorn

Im trying to deploy a flask app on AWS, I have more files but I guess the problem is in one of them.

**This is my tree:**

```
API 
      app
           app.py
           __init__.py
      wsgi.py
```

**in app.py there is :**

```
from . import create_app
app = create_app()
if __name__ == "__main__":  # Only in dev
    app.run(host="0.0.0.0", port=5000, debug=True)  # nosec
```

**on the init:**

```
from flask import Flask

def create_app() -> Flask:

"""Create Flask app."""

    app = Flask(__name__)

    # accepts both /endpoint and /endpoint/ as valid URLs
    app.url_map.strict_slashes = False
    
    
    return app
```

And on the wsgi there is:

```
from app.app import app

if __name__ == "__main__":
    app.run()
```

**using gunicorn :**

```
gunicorn -b 127.0.0.1:5000 wsgi:app
```

**I am supposed to get:**

```
[2023-09-27 17:19:50 -0500] [5871] [INFO] Starting gunicorn 21.2.0
[2023-09-27 17:19:50 -0500] [5871] [INFO] Listening at: http://127.0.0.1:5000 (5871)
[2023-09-27 17:19:50 -0500] [5871] [INFO] Using worker: sync
[2023-09-27 17:19:50 -0500] [5872] [INFO] Booting worker with pid: 5872
```

**but then I get(I got the logs above but after that this message appear and start again and again):**

```
usage: gunicorn [-h] [--history HISTORY] [-c CONFIG] [-d] [-e ONLY_EXECUTORS | -x EXCLUDE_EXECUTORS] [--no-ansi]
                [--skip-self-test]
                [command ...]
gunicorn: error: unrecognized arguments: -b
```

**How do I fix this?**

Comment: This might be a duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32802303/python-flask-gunicorn-error-unrecognized-arguments